# Angular 2+: How to Submit search form from parent component and display search result in Child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-components, angular-formbuilder

I have parent component where I submit form by clicking search to search data in table grid that is in child component which is shared component that being used by other component as well. I wanted to pass form data to this child component and display result on table grid.

Is using @ViewChild decorator to call function and @Input decorator to pass form data to child component would be the way to do it. or is there a better approach?